# Parsing a JSON in angular js for a specific field

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, parsing

I am not able to parse the following JSON in angular js to retrieve data field.

**My current JSON:**

```
temp={
    "data": [{
        "spotId": 9,
        "address1": "2 townsend",
        "address2": "apt 111",
        "city": "sanjose",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "97878",
        "spotType": "garage",
        "rateHr": "2",
        "rateMonthly": "200",
        "description": "destination",
        "carSize": 1,
        "x1": 38,
        "y1": -122,
        "image": null,
        "spotBooked": ""
    }],
    "status": 200,
    "config": {
        "method": "JSONP",
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "url": "http://localhost:8080/sparking/spot/getAllSpots?callback=JSON_CALLBACK",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        }
    },
    "statusText": "load"
}
```

**I need to extract "data" field value which would be:**

```
[{
    "spotId": 9,
    "address1": "2 townsend",
    "address2": "apt 111",
    "city": "sanjose",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "97878",
    "spotType": "garage",
    "rateHr": "2",
    "rateMonthly": "200",
    "description": "destination",
    "carSize": 1,
    "x1": 38,
    "y1": -122,
    "image": null,
    "spotBooked": ""
}]
```

I tried temp.data and temp['data'] but i cannot seem to extract the data part.
Please help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question? If your JSON is as above, then you should just be able to call json.data or json['data'] to retrieve the data property of your JSON object, just like regular javascript. It sounds like there's more to it than that?

Comment: In addition to @mofojed, if that is not possible you could write a little javascript function to clean the first and last part of the JSON data. let us know what you think.

Comment: What is the specific problem?

Comment: @mofojed I tried but it didnt help. I guess its simple, but im not able to retrieve this part.

Comment: I am confused that looks like a JavaScript object def. not JSON.  temp.data should get what you are after.  You could possible post more code if you are still having problems.